# The != statement in the while loop is returning True even when it shouldn't - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

In the password function, I am trying to make the user enter a password and if he/she inputs the wrong password, then give them another chance to write the correct password or just simply quit.
The problem which I am facing is if I enter the wrong password, and then if i use TRY AGAIN, then even if I write the correct password(i.e, 1234), it still says INCORRECT PASSWORD!

To check what was wrong, I used `print(answer, type(answer))` and `print(passwd, type(passwd))` to see if they were actually the exact same or not (which they were btw). I also used `print(answer != passwd)` to see if this was causing the issue and it was. It is returning `True` even after both answer and passwd are equal. Please suggest what I should do.

```
passwd = '1234'


def password():
    global passwd
    answer = input("ENTER THE PASSWORD:\t")
    print(answer, type(answer))
    print(passwd, type(passwd))
    while answer != passwd:
        print(answer != passwd)
        print('INCORRECT PASSWORD!')
        print("1. TRY AGAIN.\n2. QUIT")
        ans = input("Answer(1/2):\t")
        while ans not in ['1', '2']:
            print("Incorrect input.")
            ans = input("Answer(1/2):\t")
        if ans == '1':
            password()
        elif ans == '2':
            print("Bye!")
            quit()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "It is returning True even after both answer and passwd are equal." What part of your code do you think should cause them to become equal? Why? In your own words, what do you think happens when you call `password()` from within that function? What do you think will happen when that call returns?

Comment: `print(answer != passwd)` evaluates to `true` when the input made is not equal to `passwd` value as per your code.

Comment: First, if I write the incorrect password, my code asks me to try again. For that, I call the function again, which asks for the password again. Now, if I enter the correct password shouldn't both answer and passwd be equal and teh code shouldn't execute the while loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        password()
```

This **does not** mean "go back to the start of the function". It means "call the function again, as a *completely new action*; let it use its own *completely separate* set of local variables; figure out what is returned; and then *continue from this point* after it returns".

In other words: it means the *exact same thing* that it would mean if you called *any other function*.

When the new function call happens, it prompts for `input` again and you give it matching input. That means the `while` loop does not run, and the end of the function is reached - for that call.

Then it returns back to where it was in the old function call (just like it would if any other function had been called), with **no effect** on the local `answer`. So now `answer != passwd` because `answer != passwd` before, and neither value changed. `passwd` is global, but `answer` is local - and the local value is local to **this call of** the function.

You should try to rethink your logic, draw a flowchart, and re-write it without the recursive call. Make sure you understand how `break` and `continue` work, as you may find them useful.

Comment: Okay thanks. Is it okay to post my corrected code back in this thread?

Comment: It's better not to. If you run into a new issue, ask a new question. It would be my responsibility, as the answerer, to give code, but I don't think it's necessary here. It's better that anyone who comes across this later, sees the original code, in order to understand the problem described in the question.

Comment: There are probably already a few duplicates of basically this question, but it's hard to find something like this... because everyone who has such a problem, will ask about it in a slightly different way, and encounter the problem in a different context.

Comment: *"It's better that anyone who comes across this later, sees the original code"* - And they still would, wouldn't they? The OP's answer wouldn't change the question at all.

Comment: Oh. It sounded like the proposal was to edit the question. Yes, it's perfectly acceptable to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) on Stack Overflow in the answer section.

Comment: I made it work using a `return answer` at the end of the function and also setting `answer = None` before the function definition below the passwd variable

Answer (score 0):

Personnaly speaking, your main problem was the order of using while loops. I have managed to solve your problem with the `password` function by editing your code and changing the order of while loops and some other stuff:

```py
passwd = '1234'
def password():
    global passwd
    while True:
        answer = input("ENTER THE PASSWORD:\t")
        if answer != passwd:
          wrongAnswer = input("1. TRY AGAIN.\n2. QUIT\nAnswer(1/2):\t")
          while wrongAnswer != "1" and wrongAnswer != "2":
            print("Incorrect input.")
            wrongAnswer = input("Answer(1/2):\t")
          if wrongAnswer == "2":
            print("Bye!")
            break
        else:
          print("Password is correct! Goodby")
          break
```

##### Example output

```
ENTER THE PASSWORD: 8765
1. TRY AGAIN.
2. QUIT
Answer(1/2):    1
ENTER THE PASSWORD: 8765
1. TRY AGAIN.
2. QUIT
Answer(1/2):    1
ENTER THE PASSWORD: 1234
Password is correct! Goodby
```

Comment: Thank you! I have implemented it in my code. With a few changes yo suit my code and it works perfectly. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
passwd = '1234'
# I added answer = None for the first function call
answer = None              


def password():
    global passwd
    # The global answer ensures I use whatever the latest value of answer is(defined by the return statement at teh end of function)
    global answer         
    answer = input("ENTER THE PASSWORD:\t")
    print(answer, type(answer))
    print(passwd, type(passwd))
    while answer != passwd:
        print(answer != passwd)
        print('INCORRECT PASSWORD!')
        print("1. TRY AGAIN.\n2. QUIT")
        ans = input("Answer(1/2):\t")
        while ans not in ['1', '2']:
            print("Incorrect input.")
            ans = input("Answer(1/2):\t")
        if ans == '1':
            password()
        elif ans == '2':
            print("Bye!")
            quit()
    # This would return the answer and change the global variable
    return answer          


password()
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to include an else statement or answer == passwd

```
passwd = '1234'


def password():
    global passwd
    answer = input("ENTER THE PASSWORD:\t")
    print(answer, type(answer))
    print(passwd, type(passwd))
    while answer != passwd:
        print(answer != passwd)
        print('INCORRECT PASSWORD!')
        print("1. TRY AGAIN.\n2. QUIT")
        ans = input("Answer(1/2):\t")
        while ans not in ['1', '2']:
            print("Incorrect input.")
            ans = input("Answer(1/2):\t")
        if ans == '1':
            password()
        elif ans == '2':
            print("Bye!")
            quit()
    else:
        print('correct')
```